# start executable in scripts with output redirect

Tags: batch-file, redirect

I have a batch script that I use to start and stop a service.  The whole script is encapsulated in a subroutine so that i can do output redirect:

```
call :sub >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output%LogFilename%.txt
@exit /b 0

:sub

.

start cgsservice.exe -c config\cgs.json

.
```

The problem that I am having is that after starting the service using the script I CANT run the script again to stop the service.  I get the following error:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I know what the issue is but I dont know how to fix it.  The issue is the redirect to the log file, since the service is running it wont let me run the script again because it cant access the `output%LogFilename%.txt` file.  Ones I kill the service manually im able to run the script again.  Any ideas how to solve this issue with out getting rid of the redirect

Comment: Is this a Windows Service (e.g. shows in the Service Listing) you are trying to start?

Comment: no its just a exe i start in a new window by running: start cgsservice.exe -c config\cgs.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to "reclaim" the log file while the process is running. Instead you will have to stop the process which has a lock on it. You can automate the stop by adding this line prior to your call to `:sub`:

```
REM Stop any running instances of the service.
REM This is needed to release the lock on the log file.
TaskKill /im cgsservice.exe /f
```

Note this is the same as forcefully terminating the application, so I'm not sure what ramifications it may have. You can try without the `/f` switch (which will attempt a graceful closing) to see if the process stops this way.

Your other option would be to just have a separate log file for the *cgsservice.exe* process, but I'm not sure how that would fit into your workflow. To implement this, update the line:

```
call :sub >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output%LogFilename%_cgsservice.txt
```

Note that doing this will cause a lock on the alternate log file until the *cgsservice.exe* process is terminated. You can use the same `TaskKill` statement as above to stop it.

If you want to check if *cgsservice.exe* is not started and then start it, this should do it:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`TaskList /FI "IMAGENAME eq cgsservice.exe"`) DO (
    REM Check against the result of TaskList when no matches are found.
    IF "%%A"=="INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." (
        REM Service is not started. Start it now.
        START cgsservice.exe -c config\cgs.json
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey Jason having the cgsservice log somewhere else would be ideal. I have the following line but it still does not work:               tasklist /nh /fi "IMAGENAME eq cgsservice.exe" | find /i "cgsservice.exe" >> nul  || start cgsservice.exe -c config\cgs.json >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CSoutput.txt 2>&1

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with your line above. I've updated the answer above to reflect pointing it to a different log file.

Comment: This would not work for me.  What I want is to be able to run the script again without having to kill cgsservice.exe.  Is there a way  to do this?  Like you mentioned above can I separate log file for :sub and  cgsservice so that im able to run the script again with out having to kill cgservices.

Comment: Oh, so you want to leave _cgsservice.exe_ running if it is already started, otherwise start it?

Comment: thats exactly what I am trying to do.